# Assistance in Excel Formula with SUMIF/IF statement

Tags: excel, wps

[image]

The sheet above shows Machine run time and loss time and I have assigned a loss grade for each incase there is any. (A, B, C, D, E, F).

[image]

This Sheet shows the total loss for each machine.

I want to calculate all the loss time for each grade and machine. For instance, if loss grade is A, only the loss time should be calculated with a A loss grade.
Let me know if you need more information.
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Sumifs:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$F5:$AA5,Sheet1!$F$3:$AA$3,"Loss Mins",Sheet1!$G5:$AB5,D$1)
```

[image]

for first three rows.